# Wordpress Comments

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a website were a client wants to display a random testimonials that rotates on refresh. The testimonials being used are just comments people leave. So right I'm pretty much pulling the comments excerpt but I'm having trouble getting it to pull a random comment, it just pulls the latest. Is there a way to do this? This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php 

        $args = array(
        'status' => approve,
        'number' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        );

        $comments = get_comments($args); ?>
        <h3 class="side-heading">Customer Tesimonials</h3>
            <div class="testimonials-inner">
                <div class="testimonials-inner-inner">
                <?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
                    <p><?php
                        $title = get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID);
                        echo get_avatar( $comment, '53' );
                        //echo '<span class="recommauth">' . ($comment->comment_author) . '</span>';
                        ?>"<?php
                        echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 72 ); ?>"
                    </p>
                <?php }  ?>

                <br />

                <a class="re" href="/"><h4 class="butt-sub">Tell Your Story</h4></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: At first glance the code looks fine. Try disabling plugins. WP Sticky for instance has been known to cause problems.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments - valid values for `order` are `ASC` and `DESC` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

orderby=rand does not work for WordPress comments, only posts. See the link below for more info.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-random-comment

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested code, but something like this?

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'status' => 'approve',
    );

    $all_comments = get_comments($args);
    $random_key = array_rand($all_comments, 1);

    $comments = array($all_comments[$random_key]); ?>
```